# Will app/game get faster after it is published?

Tags: ios, debugging, testing

I am wondering if the test build of my app on my phone will have the same speed as it will after it has been released to the app store. I am guessing that the debugging and checking for errors take some of the processing power and my game will speed up when actually released.

Is this true or is it flawed logic? And if the performance does get better how much will it influence things like my frame-rate?

Comment: Try a test-flight build or an Instruments build

Comment: @Paulw11 will those show the true speed, as I have used the time profiler and it seems to not majorly effect performance.

Comment: the time profiler should be pretty close to a release build. A TestFlight build is the exact build and code that will be released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your application in debug mode will hurt the performance. You can run the application in release mode to see how it will perform from the app store. You just need to change your build scheme.

http://pinkstone.co.uk/deploying-your-app-from-xcode-to-a-device-with-release-build-configuration/